# Please add yubico OpenID to the list of "shortcut" openID addresses

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, openid

yubico recently fixed their openID server and it works with stack overflow (and i assume that means it will work with the rest)

the address is http://openid.yubico.com/server.php

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there should be a button for every existing OpenId, otherwise we'll have a page full of buttons.

I think the one we have are enough (and they are the most popular ones anyway)!

Comment: or are they the most popular because they are the ones you have???????.. Normally I would agree with you but the yubico technology is really neat and I think it would be a good thing to promote it over all.

Comment: "or are they the most popular because they are the ones you have???????" Demonstrably no. The services listed were all popular before StackOverflow ever existed.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that SO made them popular. I was under the impression that kop was saying they were the most popular ones on SO. (I see can see now where i miss read)

Answer (score 2):

The services listed all have a million or more users. Yubico's technology may be "really neat", but that's likely not the criteria for inclusion.

Comment: (I even think that the hardware token kind of defeats the portability of OpenID, which with a "normal" provider I can use in any browser on any device, just by remembering a single password.)

Comment: It doesn't exclude the other options but it does give thouse who want it a more secure option.

Comment: You've **got** the option of using it.